# check if a string only contains certain letters

Tags: python-3.x

In python how will create a function that checks to see if a user enter string only contains letter a and b?
 the string can be as long as the user wants but it should only contains a combination of letters a and b.
thanks.

Comment: What did google tell you? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to using regular expressions, you could also use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) checking whether [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) the characters are `in` the string `"ab"`.

```
>>> all(c in "ab" for c in "foobar")
False
>>> all(c in "ab" for c in "aaabaababbba")
True
```

Comment: but if the string only contains the letter a or b, it will return False. I want it to return true even if it is a and b seprate.

Comment: Thank You, I understand it now. My code works great. This is what I did to see if my variable contained a and or b if they didn't it returned False.
if all(c in "ab" for c in var):
            return False

Comment: Well, then you got it backwards. Use `if all(...): return True` or better, just `return all(...)` instead. So, does it work now?

Comment: I returned False because I wanted the loop to end if the string contained ab.

Comment: Wait, what loop? You totally lost me. `all` will automatically stop when it finds something other than a or b. But it does not test whether the string contains ab, but whether _all_ the characters in the string are a or b. If this is not what you want, please specify your question.

Comment: You were right, I did had it backwards. Now it returns exactly what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `(a|b)*$` to check whether the string contains only a and b

CODE:

```
import re
import sys

prog = re.compile('(a|b)*$')

str ="""aaabbb"""

if prog.match(str):
    print "String matches"
else:
    print "String doesn't match"
```

Comment: if my varibale is var. i would do var.regex(a|b|)?